# facebook like button dont appear in the position i define

Tags: javascript, facebook

since today facebook like button dont appear in the position i have always seen it on my site, is there a problem with FB?

Comment: I suggest you post some code and explain what you are trying to do. Also check the facebook developer documentation for any changes that could have affected the positioning.

Comment: doesn't look noticeably different on my blog. have you changed your css perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem with the xfbml version. We didn't change anything on our website however the button appeared not were it was before.

In our case we had centered the button, suddenly it appeared some kind of right aligned, but we couldn't find the exact problem in the code that caused it.

However we could fix it with this css:

```
.div-around-the-button iframe {left:0;}
```

Since Facebook positions the iframe absolute this css puts it back were we want it. However might be totally different in other cases.

Comment: yes i resolve the problem, but yes that's the idea , i added this:  #fb_like span{ display: inline; }  ,   fb_like is the div i created myself to throw all the FB content , inside this a FB span markup with a css inline width was the cause of my problem(the problem was only on firefox)

Comment: and it's almost the same as inside this span is the iframe:  <span><iframe></iframe></span>, cheers.